# Facing issue in using Codemirror . Correct syntax to execute command which is in merge.js

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am trying to develop a online diff tool . Currently it is showing the differences between the two files. 
I also need previous diff and next diff feature. 
According to documentation there are commands "goNextDiff" and "goPrevDiff" for it. I have pasted relevant code . panel1 and panel2 are populated by ajax call . I am getting the content and diff is showing in the panel. I just want one diff at a time when he click on next diff button it should go to the next diff.
I have two buttons which try to execute these commands. I am not sure about the syntax for it.

```
    </div>
    <!-- JS code for the second panel -->
    <div id="panel1" style="display:none">

    </div>
    <!-- the placehorder for the merge/kdiff interface -->
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
  </body>
    <button id = "prevdiff" disabled onclick> Previous Difference </button>
    <button id = "nextdiff" disabled> Next Difference </button>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    dv = CodeMirror.MergeView(document.getElementById("placeholder"), {
    value: a1[0],
    orig:  a2[0],
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: "javascript",

    highlightDifferences: true
    });

    var prev = document.getElementById("prevdiff");
    var next = document.getElementById("nextdiff");
    prev.disabled = false;
    next.disabled = false;
    prev.onclick = function(){ console.log("prevdiff"); this.execCommand("goPrevDiff"); console.log("prevdiff1");};
    next.onclick = function(){ console.log("nextdiff"); this.goNextDiff; console.log("nextdiff1");};




    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to execute **goNextDiff** and **goPrevDiff** commands using the execCommand method on the CodeMirror Object ([link](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#execCommand)). In your case CodeMirror instance is an *edit* member of MerveView object referenced by variable *dv*, so you will have to call:

```
dv.edit.execCommand("goNextDiff");
dv.edit.execCommand("goPrevDiff");
```

Of course this will just change the cursor position in the editor. I didn't find a way to highlight a specific block, that's why in my own project (https://easydiff.com) I used 2 separate instances of CodeMirror and managed diff calculations and blocks highlighting with my own code.